# Error : package or namespace load failed for ‘imputeTS

Tags: r, imputets

I'm trying to load inputeTS package in my R version 3.6.3 running on databricks. I wrote following command

```
install.packages('imputeTS',dependencies=TRUE)
```

I'm getting message

```
The downloaded source packages are in
‘/tmp/RtmpgzU1J2/downloaded_packages
```

But while trying to load the package using

```
library('imputeTS')
```

I'm getting error message

```
 package or namespace load failed for ‘imputeTS’: Error : package or namespace load failed for ‘imputeTS’: object ‘after_stat’ is not exported by 'namespace:ggplot2'
```

Can you suggest me how to resolve the issue?

Comment: What is your version of `ggplot2`? What is the return value of  `packageVersion('ggplot2')`? In `‘3.3.2’` that error doesn't occur, time to update?

Comment: @RuiBarradas, Thanks. I will update `ggplot2`

Comment: Hi @RuiBarradas, I have ggplot2 version 3.2.1. I tried to upgrade it using `update.packages("ggplot2")` but after running this, `packageVersion('ggplot2')` is showing 3.2.1. Can you please suggest me how do I upgrade it?

Comment: Try `install.packages("ggplot2")`. If you have upgraded R and want to update *all* installed packages use `update.packages`.

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be resolved by installing a newer version of `ggplot2` (which is used internally by imputeTS to create the plots)

Just run

```
 install.packages("ggplot2")
```

And then go on with the installation of `imputeTS`

```
 install.packages('imputeTS',dependencies=TRUE)
```

It is a known issue  (see https://github.com/SteffenMoritz/imputeTS/issues/48 )
and with the next CRAN version there should be an update that includes a better error message indicating that you need to update your ggplot2 version.